# jsp / spring-mvc exception on render - how to get custom error page and log the exception

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc

If an exception occurs in the service or controller, it is handled by spring's HandlerExceptionResolvers. However, if there is an exception in a .jsp processing (for example - `PropertyNotFoundException`, happens even with JSTL), then spring does not pass this through its exception handling mechanism. Further more, it is not considered an error 500, so the `<error-page>` configuration is not taken into account

Instead, the exception is propagated to the servlet container. Which is fine, but I can't actually get the behaviour I want:

- show a (500) error page
- log the exception

My current setup:

- the 500.jsp has `isErrorPage=true`
- all jsps include a common file, which has `<%@ page errorPage="500.jsp" %>`

What happens is - the exception is not recorded anywhere. And the error page is not shown. Instead, the requested page is shown half-rendered. If I increase the buffer size (enough to reach the problematic piece of code), only then the error page is shown. (again, no logging)

So, how do I achieve what I want? Without changing the buffer size, without using `<c:catch>`, and without `ex.printStackTrace()` in the error page)

Comment: What ViewResolver are you using?

Comment: InternalResourceViewResolver with JstlView. Spring 3.1.0.SNAPSHOT. Tomcat 7

Comment: Bozho, did you ever solve this one in a good way?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>package.of.ErrorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlets/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/servlets/error</location>
</error-page>
```

In the ErrorServlet implement `doService` method, because servlet container will forward there for any current action ( GET, POST, etc ).

Add this helper method

```
    public static < T extends Throwable > T getExceptionFromRequest (
            final Class< T > exception_class,
            final HttpServletRequest request                
        )
    {
        final T ret_val =
            exception_class.cast(
                request.getAttribute( SERVLET_EXCEPTION_ATTR )
            );

        if ( ret_val != null )
        {
            return ret_val;
        }

        return
            exception_class.cast(
                request.getAttribute( JSP_EXCEPTION_ATTR )
            );
    }
```

And these 2 constants:

```
    public final static String SERVLET_EXCEPTION_ATTR =
        "javax.servlet.error.exception";

    public final static String JSP_EXCEPTION_ATTR =
        "javax.servlet.jsp.jspException";
```

This has been working for me in Tomcat.

Comment: hm..I'll verify that tomorrow. But even though it works, I don't like it that much - it is a workaround at best. I "sense" a tomcat bug somewhere.

Comment: @Bozho. `javax.servlet.jsp.jspException` is a Tomcat hack and maybe it's not even needed anymore, but `javax.servlet.error.exception` is straight from Servlet API 2.3 (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Servlets/servletapi2.3/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) that has an empty `preHandle()` and `postHandle()`, but that caters for Exceptions in `afterComplete()`?

Comment: that indeed may do the logging part, but the exception will be propagated to the servlet container anyway, so the buffer issue remains

Comment: Use a servlet filter to wrap the response with a memory only output stream. Then discard the content if there has been an error and output your http 500 and custom message.

Comment: well, yeah, I know I can add a filter, but that too will be a  workaround. I reported an issue to tomcat, let's see what will be their explanation/suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are 2 issues:

1. You can set the buffer size directly in your JSP to avoid the half-rendering; since you're already setting `isErrorPage` this would follow your current design
2. You can log the error from the 500 page, [as per this example](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?13802-Exception-handling-of-exceptions-thrown-in-jsp-s)